# Strange behavior when returning a const reference with a const function

Tags: c++

I have managed to fix, or rather work around, the issue, so I'm not looking for help but I'm just really curious what the underlying reason in the language is.

I have the following code in my (cocos2d-x, but I don't think that's relevant) game:

```
const Size& Checkbox::getContentSize() const
{
    Size size;
    size.height = label->getContentSize().width;
    size.width = label->getContentSize().height + hPadding + checkbox->getContentSize().height;

    return size;
}
```

The function returns a Size with only the width while the height remains 0. However, if I add any code before returning, the function returns a Size containing the correct width and height.

```
const Size& Checkbox::getContentSize() const
{
    Size size;
    size.height = label->getContentSize().width;
    size.width = label->getContentSize().height + hPadding + checkbox->getContentSize().height;

    int meaninglessInteger = 10;

    return size; //size gets returned properly
}
```

It also returns properly if I do it like this:

```
const Size& Checkbox::getContentSize() const
{
    float height = label->getContentSize().width;
    float width = label->getContentSize().height + hPadding + checkbox->getContentSize().height;

    return Size(width, height); //size gets returned properly
}
```

It's a virtual function from the cocos2d-x engine itself so I can't play around with the parameters or make anything not const or a reference. Anyway, I'd just like to know what causes this behavior, and especially why it gets fixed by adding code that does nothing.

Comment: These all invoke **undefined behaviour** - you can't return a reference to a local object.

Comment: `and especially why it gets fixed by adding code that does nothing.` things like this can happen in undefined-behavior-land. Returning a reference to a local variable is never a good idea.

Comment: You should [receive a warning](http://cpp.sh/9xenr) from your compiler if you have your warnings on, **don't ignore them**

Comment: So the only proper way to do it would be to have a Size in my class which would get updated by the function and returned?

As for warnings, I get way too many about cocos's deprecated functions so it's hard to filter out anything meaningful. But neither Resharper, nor Visual Studio have warned me in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

*size* is in the stack, and it's deallocated after that you return. You're returning a reference to a variable that will be deallocated. This is undefined behavior.